# How to outline Chinese font by xeTeX?

Tags: fonts, chinese

I am try to outline some Chinese fonts by using LaTeX, which could be done by MS Word easily. Basically here is what I want:

[image]

I searched whole site and I found some topics about outline a font, where none of them related to Chinese fonts. So I am asking here again and expecting some help. Here is my least workable example, with solid font only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}
\begin{document}
  {\fontsize{72}{86} \selectfont 文字}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I am using *contour* package to solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \contourlength{.6pt}
  \contournumber{50}
  {\fontsize{72}{86} \selectfont 文字}
  \contour{black}{\fontsize{72}{86} \selectfont \textcolor{white}{文字}}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

I have below output:

[image]

Comment: Could you *show* us (with code) at least a part of your solution?