# How to create letters with a border?

Tags: fonts

I want to create letters with a border. For example, consider this:

[image]

The letter on the left is an ordinary "A". The letter on the right is a purple "A" with a black border.

How can I get an "A" with a border? I am labeling an image, so just like subtitles in a movie, the letters will need a border. I will probably need a white border.

Comment: @axscl77 I am not sure of any fonts existing to do this kind of job. However, it could be possible if you are going to define each and every font per se. Maybe, you can try a hybrid approach of trimming, clipping and redrawing your fonts.

Comment: A starting point could be: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192496/how-to-shade-text-in-different-colors

Comment: This should be possible with outline.sty. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475675/4918 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400296/4918. I‘ll also vote to close this question as duplicate of the latter one.

Comment: The package `contour.sty` may helps you...